# Reformat all scientific names in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I want to know a trick in which the Microsoft word reformat all the scientific names TO Italic form with capital first letter on first word only, automatically.

assume you have a typed document which is containing many scientific names throughout the context, how could you automatically identify and reformat scientific names effortlessly?

for instance: in the context you have many different 2-3 word-combinations which one of them is "huso huso" which is a scientific name, and you want to automatically convert it to "*Huso huso*" which is Italic and the first letter of the first word is capital. So how would you do it?

I know the "Auto correct" in MS Word can do it in a similar way, but it is not quiet good for this purpose.

Comment: You manually mark every instance and give it a different format. To ease the pain you might choose to define a custom format and apply that those those words instead of marking them and telling them to be italic. That way you can later on change the format easier.

Comment: it is manual. I need an automated way to correct thousands of pages simultaneously

Comment: Do you have any pattern that would clearly identify the scientific words within a block of text a list or similar? If you don't have any of that, there is no to easily discern which words are scientific words.

Comment: @2224614 Your needles are mixed all through your haystack. Although Word's search and replace lets you apply a style , which will help you get all instances of a repeated name, at some point you're going to have to read through the whole document to make sure everything's right.

Comment: @Seth: I think I can provide a list of scientific names, if I provide it, is there any way to teach to Word to use them in a specific format ?

Comment: @Spencer it is totally manually, it needs that I know which scientific names are used in the whole text. very time consuming and hard..

Comment: @2224614 You can't avoid some manual intervention, but you can use some tasks to reduce the amount of it. For example, you could do a word frequency list of the text. The less frequent words are likely contain all of the scientific names.

Comment: @Spencer You right. this could help. but I tried all this ways and again I am looking for a better and effortless way. assume you are working in a Journal publication with huge amounts of articles, words and papers. it is strongly needed to find an automatic tools to do it

Comment: In which case you design your documents properly upfront and consider using something like LaTeX. In order to "effortlessly" change stuff. You did a bad job (for whatever reason) writing your initial documents and now want to change them. So you will have to invest time in order to fix them. You could try to write a VBA macro that does the search and replace in order to apply a format. But you will not find a magic tool that just knows what to do.

Comment: @Seth It sounds like OP didn't write the documents; e's just the poor schlub tasked with getting them into shape for the journal. But, agreed, there is no magic tool.

Comment: If I provide such a database containing thousands of scientific names, would you please let me know how I can make a VB macro to use that database as a dictionary in order to correct words format ?

Comment: 1) Find a tool to extract a list of all the unique words in the document (I forget whether there is a built-in tool for this). 2) Manually clean up that list (delete irrelevant words, look for words that are part of multi-word terms and make those complete terms). 3) Create a style (capitalization & italics). 4) write VBA to iterate through the list and do a global find & replace for the style on each one.  The details of implementing this would be beyond the intended scope of a question.